# Changing Hostname on CentOS 7

Tags: linux, centos

What is difference between those two methods for changing host name on CentOS 7?
I want to setup this centOS with a FQDN.

The first way is `vi /etc/sysconfig/network` and `vi /etc/hosts` files. but this way somehow wont work, after I changed the host name in this 2 locations, rebooted, run `hostname` it still shows me hostname as "localhost"

The second way after research is using `hostnamectl set-hostname` or `hostname set-hostname xxx.xxx --static` command.

If using 2nd way to change hostname, it modifies which file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On old versions of CentOS you could set the system static hostname in `/etc/sysconfig/network` by setting:

```
HOSTNAME=myhost.example.com
```

This would be processed by the system init scripts and set the kernel's hostname at boot.

This is no longer the case in CentOS 7, nor any systemd-based system. On such systems, the static hostname is stored in `/etc/hostname`, and set with `hostnamectl`.

While it's possible to simply put the hostname in `/etc/hostname`, running `hostnamectl set-hostname` will cause it to take effect immediately, without requiring a reboot.

(And, it was never the case that the hostname could be set by changing `/etc/hosts`. This file simply overrides name resolution in case DNS is not available or unwanted.)

Answer (score 1):

Both commands

```
sudo hostname --boot some.hostname.example
```

and

```
sudo hostnamectl set-hostname some.hostname.example
```

set the hostname in file `/etc/hostname`